# Catenary equation in 3D

Tags: 3d, parametric

I have two points with coordinates A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). There is a third point which is lowest point of the catenary curve. I only know z-coordinate of this third point. I need to find coordinates of the points that lie on this catenary that passes through these 3 points. I am interested in coordinates that lie in between A and B.

Comment: Try it first in the plane, then adapt.

Comment: Is the axis of symmetry of the catenary supposed to be vertical, or are we allowed to rotate it? If your problem comes from physics (hanging chains, etc.), then presumably the axis of the catenary has to be vertical, so that it's aligned with the direction of gravity.

Comment: yes..it is vertical...i have all the equations of catenary in 2d..nothing in 3d..

Answer (score 0):

Shift (translate) both points together so that the first point lies at origin. Create all the needed  coordinates between origin and displaced point. Rotate in the plane through $ \tan ^{-1} (y/x) $ so new anchor points are:

$$ (0,0,0) -(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)$$

Hope the catenary length is given and you know how to get the coordinates when endpoints at different $z$ coordinates are given. This done, shift the entire catenary back, bringing end points where they were held/fixed.

Answer (score 0):

First apply a rotation around a vertical axis to let $y_1=y_2$, and subtract the given $z_a$ ($a$ for apex).

In these transformed coordinates, the equation of the catenary is

$$z=A\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x-x_a}A\right)-1\right)$$

with two unknown parameters $A$ and $x_a$.

With the two given points, we form the system

$$z_1=A\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x_1-x_a}A\right)-1\right),\\
z_2=A\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x_2-x_a}A\right)-1\right).$$

You can eliminate $x_a$ by

$$x_a=x_1-A\,\text{arcosh}\left(\frac{z_1}A+1\right)$$
and
$$z_2=A\left(\cosh\left(\frac{x_2-x_1\,}A+\text{arcosh}\left(\frac{z_1}A+1\right)\right)-1\right).$$

This "appetizing" equation needs to be solved for $A$ by numerical methods.