# Catenary Equation of a plane (3D)

Tags: geometry

A catenary equation models a curve supported by two points, when solely acted on by gravity. The common formula is given as

$y= a \cosh(\frac{x}{a})$

where $a$ is a constant regulating the steepness of the curve.

My question is, is there a similar equation for modelling a structure in 3D. For example, if I had some points $(x,y)$ (perhaps defined on a circle, but not necessarily), can I create a parabolic structure as in this figure? [Paraboloid of Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Paraboloid_of_Revolution.svg)

Note: This is not the same as question [Catenary equation in 3D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1138517/catenary-equation-in-3d), which is asking about a catenary curve in a 3D space, I am looking for how a 3D structure can be modelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the equation of the surface generated by the rotation of a catenary around its axis of symmetry (taken as $z$ axis), then it is simply:
$$
z=a\cosh\left({\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over a}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm a bit confused however. 
Say I define some points $x,y$ (say as a plane). Then for the point (0,0), using that equation I would get $z=a$. This means that in this case, $z>x$ and $z>y$. If $z$ is a measurement of the "height" of a point on this surface, how can it be higher than my initial coordinates?
I have run a quick graph in matlab to show my issue, the red curve is a 2D catenary curve, then yellow flat plane is my plane of coordinates (that I'm imaging the surface is "hanging" from), and the purple surface is $z$ (http://imgur.com/7Jwa54X)

Comment: Well, the plane equation appearing in your question suffers from the same disease, I'm afraid: for $x=0$ you get $y=a$. If you need the lowest point of the surface to touch the $(x,y)$ plane, then simply subtract $a$: $$z=a\cosh\left({\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\over a}\right)-a.$$